# How do I update my meter widget (python, ttkbootstrap) using the results I've gathered from a pyspeedtest?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttkbootstrap

I am trying to update my meter widget with the results of a ping test using pyspeedtest, but I keep getting the error:
"TypeError: Meter.configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"
The ping function works without any issues, I just can't seem to figure out how to pass the ping result to the meters "amountused" parameter to change the widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
import pyspeedtest

root = Tk()
window = style.master
window_width = 300
window_height = 300
root.resizable(False, False)

ping_meter = ttk.Meter

ping_meter(
    master=root,
    metersize=300,
    padding=20,
    amountused=0,
    metertype='semi',
    subtext='milliseconds',
    interactive=False
).grid(sticky=N, row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

myping = IntVar()

def ping_test():
   t = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest(e1.get())
   myping.set(t.ping())
   ping_meter.configure(amountused = myping)

Label(root, text="Website URL:").grid(sticky=W, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)
Label(root, text="Ping Result:").grid(sticky=W, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

result = Label(root, text="", textvariable=myping).grid(sticky=W, row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
b = Button(root, text="Check", command=ping_test)
b.grid(sticky=W, row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe use `ping_meter = ttk.Meter(master=root, ...`, instead of having `ping_meter = ttk.Meter` and `ping_meter(master=root` on separate lines. How it is right now, you initialize `ping_meter`, but don't assign the initialized class to a variable.

Comment: Hi @SylvesterKruin, I made some adjustments based on your suggestion.. Now the meter is updating it's amountused text, however the result is "PY_VAR3" instead of the numerical ping value result. Any thoughts?

Comment: @StevenKlinck Use `get()` to get its content: `ping_meter.configure(amountused=myping.get())`

Answer (score 0):

the line `ping_meter = ttk.Meter` creates the variable `ping_meter` which is just the class `ttk.Meter`. therefore `.configure()` doesn't work. when you create an instance it isn't assigned to any variable, instead try doing this to create an instance of `ttk.Meter`, note that `.grid()` is called separately.

```
ping_meter = ttk.Meter(
    master=root,
    metersize=300,
    padding=20,
    amountused=0,
    metertype='semi',
    subtext='milliseconds',
    interactive=False
)
ping_meter.grid(sticky=N, row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

also in `ping_test()`  use `ping_meter.configure(amountused = t)` instead.

Comment: Hi @Hadrian, Thanks for commenting. I did as you and SylvesterKruin suggested.. Now the meter is updating it's amountused text, however the result is "PY_VAR3" instead of the numerical ping value result. Any thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer